# Test Class not passed

Tags: apex, code-coverage, opportunity-lineitem, unit-test

Here is my test bulkify test class and my actuall trigger handler methods. I dont know why but my code coverage is %76 and still it says test is not passed.. Is there anyone can help me about this situation.

```
   @isTest
   private class OrdLineItemTestClass {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

     List<OrderProducts__c> BulkOli=new List<OrderProducts__c>();
    List<OrderProducts__c> updateBulkOli=new List<OrderProducts__c>();

     Order__c orderNew=new Order__c();
     orderNew.Name='test-Order';
     orderNew.CloseDate__c=system.Today();
     orderNew.Stage='Prospecting';

     Product2 productNew=new Product2();
     ProductNew.Name='test-Product';
     ProductNew.isActive=true;

     insert productNew;
     insert orderNew;

    for(integer i=0 ; i<150; i++)
    {
        OrderProducts__c oli=new OrderProducts__c(
            Products__c=ProductNew.Id,
            Quantity__c=4,
            SalesPrice__c=35000,
            Name='test',
            Order_mas__c=OrderNew.Id
        );
        BulkOli.add(oli);
    }

    test.startTest();

        insert BulkOli;

            for(OrderProducts__c InsertEquals: BulkOli)
        {
            system.assertEquals('test', oliEquals.Name);
        }

        for(OrderProducts__c updateOli: BulkOli)
        {
            OrderProducts__c oli=new OrderProducts__c(
                Id=updateOli.Id,
                Quantity__c=6
            );
            updateBulkOli.add(oli);
        }
        update  updateBulkOli;

        for(OrderProducts__c oliEquals: BulkOli)
        {
            system.assertEquals(6, oliEquals.Quantity__c);
        }

        delete BulkOli;

    test.stopTest();
  }
  }
```

---

```
  public class OrderLineItemProcess{
public OrderLineItemProcess(){}

public void onAfterInsert(Map<Id,OrderProducts__c> TriggerNew)
{
    Map<Id, Order__c> ords = new Map<Id, Order__c>();

    set<Id> productIds=new set<Id>();
    Pricebook2 standartpb = [select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true and isActive= true limit 1];


    for(OrderProducts__c record: TriggerNew.values()) {
        productIds.add(record.products__c);
        ords.put(record.Id, null);
    }
    Map<Id, PricebookEntry> prices = new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>();

    for(PricebookEntry pricebook: [Select Id,Product2Id,UnitPrice,Pricebook2Id From PricebookEntry Where Product2Id IN :productIds and Pricebook2Id=:standartpb.Id])
    {
        prices.put(pricebook.Product2Id,pricebook);
    }


    List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems=new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    for(OrderProducts__c record: [select Products__c,order_mas__r.OpportunityLookup__c,Quantity__c,Discount__c,Salesprice__c, LineDescription__c,OppLineItemExternalId__c from OrderProducts__c where Id IN: TriggerNew.values()]) 
    {
                OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem=new OpportunityLineItem(
                    PricebookEntryId=prices.get(record.Products__c).Id,
                    OpportunityId=record.order_mas__r.OpportunityLookup__c,
                    Quantity=record.Quantity__c,
                    Discount=record.Discount__c,
                    UnitPrice=record.Salesprice__c,
                    Description=record.LineDescription__c,
                    OrdLineItemExternalId__c=record.Id
                );
         lineItems.add(oppLineItem);

    }       
        FlaG.run=false;
        insert(lineItems);  

    List<OrderProducts__c> updateOrdProductsList=new List<OrderProducts__c>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem OppExternalId : lineItems)
    {
        OrderProducts__c Updateord = new OrderProducts__c(
            Id=OppExternalId.OrdLineItemExternalId__c,
            OppLineItemExternalId__c=OppExternalId.Id
        );

        updateOrdProductsList.add(Updateord);
    }

    update updateOrdProductsList;

}
public void onAfterUpdate(List<OrderProducts__c> TriggerNew)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppList=new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    for(OrderProducts__c ordList : TriggerNew)
    {
        OpportunityLineItem opp=new OpportunityLineItem(
            Id=ordlist.OppLineItemExternalId__c,
            OpportunityId=ordList.order_mas__r.OpportunityLookup__c,
            Quantity=ordList.Quantity__c,
            Discount=ordList.Discount__c,
            UnitPrice=ordList.Salesprice__c,
            Description=ordList.LineDescription__c,
            OrdLineItemExternalId__c=ordList.Id
        );
        oppList.add(opp);
    }

    if(FlaG.run)
    {
        FlaG.run=false;
        update oppList;
    }
}

public void onBeforeDelete(Map<Id,OrderProducts__c> oldMap)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> opp=[Select Id,OrdLineItemExternalId__c from OpportunityLineItem Where OrdLineItemExternalId__c IN : oldMap.keyset() ];

    for(OpportunityLineItem opp2 :opp)
    {
        if(FlaG.run)
        {
            delete opp2;
        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests passing and test coverage are two different things. You will need to get all your tests passing and the coverage on average greater than 75% (and all your triggers above 0% coverage).

The try/catch in your test will hide any DMLExceptions and cause lines of code not to be covered. For example, if `insert BulkOli` throws a DMLException, the 10 lines or so that follow before the catch will not be covered. Best to remove the try/catch altogether and fix any problems: this might be difficult but is necessary for your test to have value.

Note that this should never be done:

```
catch(DMLexception e){}
```

and generally letting exceptions propagate rather than trying to handle them is the right thing to do in tests and most other code too.

Using `SeeAllData=true` and hard coded ids such as `01t20000003gOs6AAE` is a fragile approach because the referenced objects could be deleted or modified. It is better to create the objects as part of the test.

Ideally your test would contain more assert statements that check the results in more detail after each of the insert, update and delete operation. It is not unusual for a unit test to have more lines of code that the code it is testing.

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible. thank you for your comment, it seems like your comment will help a lot. i will write another comment after i try it thanks.

Comment: i did exactly what you said it still not passed.. I think there is an error about my logic. I need to find a trick to figure it out :/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not passed" - the test or something to do with the coverage? If the test, what assertion failed or what exception was thrown and at what line?

Comment: actually that is what i dont understand test coverage is %2 but there is noting failed or any exception..

Comment: I edited my code block can you please check it again

Comment: The platform's presentation of code coverage has got more confusing in the last couple of releases. AFAIK, the only place to get the coverage figures for an individual class is in the "Tests" tab of the Developer Console; go there immediately after running your test and open the class being tested. That will show you exactly which lines are and are not covered and guide you to the areas of your test that need changing.

Comment: Thank you again i will check it in a few hours and i will let you know

Comment: i checked error messages on console and it worked after i change id fields.. Thank you